# URLSession function similar to Alamofire's responseString?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

Because I am using cocoapods and have necessary Objective-C dependencies, I cannot use frameworks and as such cannot use Alamofire... Alamofire has a function responseString (see code below), so I need to do this natively using URLSession, how can I do this?

```
 Alamofire.request(testURL).responseString { response in
        print("\(response.result.isSuccess)")
        if let html = response.result.value {
            parseHTML(html: html)
        }
    }
```

Alamofire:

```
extension DataRequest {
    /// Creates a response serializer that returns a result string type initialized from the response data with
    /// the specified string encoding.
    ///
    /// - parameter encoding: The string encoding. If `nil`, the string encoding will be determined from the server
    ///                       response, falling back to the default HTTP default character set, ISO-8859-1.
    ///
    /// - returns: A string response serializer.
    public static func stringResponseSerializer(encoding: String.Encoding? = nil) -> DataResponseSerializer<String> {
        return DataResponseSerializer { _, response, data, error in
            return Request.serializeResponseString(encoding: encoding, response: response, data: data, error: error)
        }
    }

    /// Adds a handler to be called once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - parameter encoding:          The string encoding. If `nil`, the string encoding will be determined from the
    ///                                server response, falling back to the default HTTP default character set,
    ///                                ISO-8859-1.
    /// - parameter completionHandler: A closure to be executed once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - returns: The request.
    @discardableResult
    public func responseString(
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
        encoding: String.Encoding? = nil,
        completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<String>) -> Void)
        -> Self
    {
        return response(
            queue: queue,
            responseSerializer: DataRequest.stringResponseSerializer(encoding: encoding),
            completionHandler: completionHandler
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this code doing exactly? just perform request to testURL and then get the html data part from the response?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the reason you can not use Alamofire?  I have used it with cocoapods and objc dependencies.

Comment: I've never had problems using Alamofire in a mixed project with cocoapods (in fact, Alamofire itself is available as a pod).

Comment: no the problem is using frameworks would break my existing pods (namely the Pinterest SDK) https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3839

Comment: I've added the docs from the method in Alamofire

Comment: Hmm.  Would it work if you installed Alamofire manually as a submodule instead?

Comment: I think so but was trying to avoid since I'm only using 1 method, seems like overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential code to get the *`success`* and *`value / html`* values from `URLSessionDataTask` is

```
dataTask(url: url) { (data, response, error) in

   guard error == nil else { 
      print(error!)
      // handle error
      return 
   }

   let success : Bool
   let html : String

   if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
      success = true
      html = String(data:data!, encoding: .utf8)! // or .isoLatin1
   } else {
      success = false
      print("http response error")
      html = ""
   }

   print(html, success)
}
```

It assumes the standard text encoding (utf8). And `URLRequest` is only needed for a `POST` request.

Comment: thanks but it's crashing on `html = String(data:data!, encoding: .utf8)!` sure this line is correct? (I know the url is ok...)

Comment: The code is untested but it's supposed to work. Is the data `utf8`? When you print the data do you get the expected number of bytes?

Comment: If the code crashes at this line the encoding does not match.

Comment: I think that's it, my request is going to Google what encoding should I use?

Comment: better yet how can I determine it from the server response?

Comment: Try windows encoding (`.isoLatin1`)

Comment: That works! want to update your answer and I'll accept?

Comment: I updated the answer to provide windows/latin as an alternative. You could get the encoding from the headers ( `Content-Type`) of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data from your response, turn it into the string. Alamofire doesn't do much here.

```
public static func serializeResponseString(
    encoding: String.Encoding?,
    response: HTTPURLResponse?,
    data: Data?,
    error: Error?)
    -> Result<String>
{
    guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

    if let response = response, emptyDataStatusCodes.contains(response.statusCode) { return .success("") }

    guard let validData = data else {
        return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .inputDataNil))
    }

    var convertedEncoding = encoding

    if let encodingName = response?.textEncodingName as CFString!, convertedEncoding == nil {
        convertedEncoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(
            CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(encodingName))
        )
    }

    let actualEncoding = convertedEncoding ?? String.Encoding.isoLatin1

    if let string = String(data: validData, encoding: actualEncoding) {
        return .success(string)
    } else {
        return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .stringSerializationFailed(encoding: actualEncoding)))
    }
}
```